# How can I use todonotes \missingfigure in subcaptions subfigure environment?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, todonotes

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{Bild 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{Bild 2}
    \end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

results in errors such as `Emergency stop`, `You can't use \end in internal vertical mode.` or `Missing number, treated as zero`.

Seems to me, as if `\missingfigure` is not usable in the subfigure environment of `subcaption`.

Is there another way to use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to supply the width for each `subfigure` as in `\begin{subfigure}{2in}`. Please note that the width parameter is a mandatory argument here.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{2in}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{Bild 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{2in}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{Bild 2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You find some time for good answers, today? ;-)